# explore_lite goal select error

Tags: ros-noetic

https://youtu.be/BAvbB-LPdlI?si=obAaYYDQuKlgZRIm&t=50

explore_lite target the opposite side of the unexplored area.

I don't understand the parameters of explore_lite. Please help